# Use first frame of video as thumbnail

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-video

I am using [react-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video)

And it have a props called `poster` which is working fine. But my requirement is to get that thumbnail from video (first frame of video). If I don't use `poster` (which accept an url) then it is showing blank screen.

Any idea how to use first frame of video as thumbnail?

Thank You!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `onLoad` function callback to achieve it,

```
const player = useRef(null);
```

```
<Video
  source={{uri: uri}}
  ref={player}
  paused={true}
  style={styles.backgroundVideo}
  onLoad={() => {
    player.current.seek(0); // this will set first frame of video as thumbnail
  }}
/>
```

For more details on `onLoad` prop: [here](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video#onload)

Comment: I believe this is not working anymore! I got undefined every time.

Comment: I had to use 1 instead of 0 to get it working.

Comment: Is there a way to make a thumbnail on some specific frame/time but when user actually plays the video it starts from the beginning?